# How to use doxygen with Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, doxygen

I installed "doxygen" for Win7-32bit but I could not integrate it with "Netbeans7.3.1" for Java. Would you please help me Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Enas, I did some research and I believe I know why you can't get Doxygen to work with Netbeans 7.3.1.  The short answer it isn't supposed to work with that version.

The solution to the problem appears to be to update to Netbeans 7.4.

I must add that I haven't tried this myself but from the documentation that I read, installing Doxygen for Netbeans 7.4 is easy.

The documentation I found at http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/14326/doxygen-integration says " Use 'Tools > Plugins' action from the NetBeans IDE main menu for convenient installation of this plugin."

From what I can tell the **only** versions of Netbeans that support Doxygen are 6.2, 7.2 and 7.4.

In closing, I have not been able to test this myself.  I use NB 8.0.2 and the instructions for 7.4 do not work in 8.0.2.

I hope my research helps you.